# From "2020-06-28T06:00:18.166286Z" to "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" give an error format - Why?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to fix this error:

```
print(dt.datetime.strftime("2020-06-04T07:11:38.559105Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

> TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

I need change the format datetime "2020-06-04T07:11:38.**559105Z**" into "2020-06-04T07:11:**38Z**"

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're trying to use the `datetime.strptime` function.

I remember the difference by:

```
strptime has a p for parsing. 
strftime has an f for formatting.
```

The other issue here is that the string you are trying to parse includes microseconds but the microsecond format string `%f` is not included.

Try this:

```py
date_obj = dt.datetime.strptime("2020-06-04T07:11:38.559105Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
date_str = date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Comment: Thanks! I try with f and p, but this is not working too:

Comment: :(            print(dt.datetime.strftime("2020-06-04T07:11:38.559105Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"))
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Comment: ah sorry, that's what I get for copy-pasting, just updated again.

Comment: thanks....work with this result: 2020-06-04 07:11:38.559105... but I need to remove miliseconds (.559105) and only show  "2020-06-04 07:11:38"

Comment: I resolved temporaly as this:                                                                                                                 s="2020-06-04T07:11:38.559105Z"
print(s.split(".")[0]+'Z')

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if you have a chance!

Comment: Use %z instead of literal Z. It's not some random char, it denotes UTC.

Answer (score 1):

The `strftime` converts a datetime to string. To do the opposite, use the `strptime`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Thanks! I try with f and p, but this is not working too

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Comment: You are using the `strftime` not the `strptime`. Did you read the datetime docs?